# Loading a large dataset in chunks on Iphone using NSkeyedArchiver

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory, nskeyedarchiver

I have a large NSDictionary thats written to disk using NSkeyedArchiver. Since this dictionary may/will be very large, its not feasible to load the entire thing into memory. Whats the best best way to load up the dictionary in chunks,work with that chunk and then move on to the next etc and hence save up on memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `NSkeyedArchiver` to archive one big `NSDictionary` containing all objects.

Archive objects using `encodeObject:forKey:` unarchive using `decodeObjectForKey:`.
This way you don't need to unarchive the whole `NSDictionary` in order to retrieve just one object.

Comment: Thanks, in the end i ditched NSkeyedArchiver in favour of [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&err] ; as it resulted in a much smaller filesize. I also ended up splitting my archive into (smaller) seperate individual files and used an NSfilewrapper But ill accept your answer as its correct